# How to sort a text file line-by-line

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, sorting

I need to sort a text file in ascending order. Each line of the text file starts with an index, as seen below:

```
2       0       4         0d 07:00:38.0400009155273
3       0       4         0d 07:00:38.0400009155273
1       0       4         0d 07:00:38.0400009155273
```

The idea result would be as follows:

```
1       0       4         0d 07:00:38.0400009155273
2       0       4         0d 07:00:38.0400009155273
3       0       4         0d 07:00:38.0400009155273
```

Please note, this text file has +3 million rows and each element is naturally considered a string.

I've been messing around with this for sometime now without any luck so I figured it was time to consult with the experts. Thank you for you time!

EDIT:

I'm using windows OS with Python 3.7 in Spyder IDE. The file is not a CSV its a text file that is tab delimited. There is the possibility that not all indices are present. Forgive the noob-ness, I haven't got a lot of experience coding.

Comment: If you are on any Unix-like system: `sort -n /path/to/file`

Comment: run in in linux and it should be very fast.  sort -o out.txt input.txt

Comment: Where are you stuck?  you identified the problem: each index is *naturally* considered a string.  Thus, you have to convert it to `int` and then sort.  Or, as @FMc pointed out, simply use the `sort` command in your shell.

Comment: FYI It's always best to include your attempts of "messing around with this for sometime now" so we can know what specifically you have tried and why it was not suitable. Otherwise we may end up posting answers you've already tried and wasting everybody's time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
fn = 'filename.txt'
sorted_fn = 'sorted_filename.txt'

with open(fn,'r') as first_file:
    rows = first_file.readlines()
    sorted_rows = sorted(rows, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), reverse=False)
    with open(sorted_fn,'w') as second_file:
        for row in sorted_rows:
            second_file.write(row)
```

This should work for a text file of 3+ million rows. Using `int(x.split()[0])` will sort the first item in each row as an integer

Edited to remove close() statements

Comment: you don't need the last 2 lines in your code since using `with`  will close the files automatically

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that.

Comment: another note for performance you can limit split to 1, so, `int(x.split()[0])` can be `int(x.split(maxsplit=1)[0])` to make only one split "the number and rest of the line" since you will use the first split and other splits will be ignored

Comment: @Cooper is there a way to start the lambda function after a specific row? For example, I'd like to start after row 3 but I'm not too familiar with Lambda functions. In the past I've done something like: for x, y in enumerate(rows): if x > 3: start sorting

Comment: you can do: `sorted_rows = rows[:2]+sorted(rows[2:], key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0])`

Answer (score 2):

A one-stop solution would be to do reading, sorting and writing all with one file handle. Thanks to `'r+'` mode:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    sorted_contents =  ''.join(sorted(f.readlines(), key = lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[0])))
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(sorted_contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go about this by reading the file into lines, splitting them on whitespace and then sorting them according to a custom key; i.e., if your file were called "foo.txt":

```
with open("foo.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    sorted(lines, key=lambda line: int(line.split()[0]))
```

After that, lines should contain all lines sorted by the first column.

However, I don't know how well this would work, regarding your file size. Maybe you would have to split the file's contents into chunks that you sort one by one and then you can sort the chunks.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple `.split(' ')` to format the data into a dictionary that looks like:

```
my_data = {
 2: ['0', '4', '0d', '07:00:38.0400009155273'],
 3: ['0', '4', '0d', '07:00:38.0400009155273'],
 1: ['0', '4', '0d', '07:00:38.0400009155273']
}
```

Which you could then iterate through (assuming all keys exist) like:

```
for i in range(1, max(list(my_data.keys())) + 1):
    pass # do some computation
```

Additionally you could single out a specific value like `my_data[1]`

To be able to put your data in this form I would use the script:

```
with open("foo.txt", "r") as file:
    in_data = file.readlines()

my_data = {}
for data in in_data:
    split_info = data.split(" ")
    useful_data = [item.strip() for item in split_info[1:] if item != ""]
    my_data.update({split_info[0]: useful_data})

for key in sorted(my_data.keys()):
    print("{}: {}".format(key, my_data[key]))
```

Which prints:

> 1: ['0', '4', '0d', '07:00:38.0400009155273']
>
> 2: ['0', '4', '0d', '07:00:38.0400009155273']
>
> 3: ['0', '4', '0d', '07:00:38.0400009155273']

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas it will help you immensely. Assuming the file is a csv do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('to/file', sep='\t', index='Name of column with index')  # Guessing that your file is tab separated
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

Now you have a dataframe with all of the information you need sorted. I'd suggest digging into pandas since it will really help you out. Here is a link to get started https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html

Comment: pandas has a considerable memory overhead which may prevent this from succeeded on large datasets. We were unable to use it on similarly sized datasets for this reason (record counts in the low millions).

Comment: In that case you could try using Dask http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html of course it might be an axe when you are looking for a scalpel

Answer (score 0):

Here's an edited version of a perfectly good answer you already have. The edits
might be useful as you learn more about coding. The key points:

- When writing a program, it's often best to do your coding with a small sample
  of the input data (for example, a file with 30 rows rather than 3 million):
  your program will run quicker; debugging output will be smaller and more
  readable; and some other reasons as well. Thus, rather than hard-coding the
  path to the input file (or other files), take those file paths as command-line
  parameters, using `sys.argv`.

  ```
  import sys

  in_path = sys.argv[1]
  out_path = sys.argv[2]
  ```
- If you are holding a lot of data in memory (enough to make you think you are
  close to your machine's limits), don't create unneeded copies of the data. For
  example, to ignore the first few lines, don't store the original lines in
  `rows` and then get the desired values using `rows[2:]`: that creates a new
  list. Instead add the conditional logic to your initial creation of `rows` (the
  example uses a list comprehension, but you can do the same thing in a regular
  `for` loop). And if you need to sort that data, don't use `sorted()`, which
  creates a new list; instead, sort the list in place, with `rows.sort()`.

  ```
  with open(in_path, 'r') as fh:
      rows = [line for i, line in enumerate(fh) if i > 1]
      rows.sort(key = lambda x: int(x.split(None, 1)[0]))
  ```
- There's no reason to nest the writing with-block inside the reading
  with-block. If you don't have a good reason to connect two different tasks
  within a program, explicitly separate them. This is among of the most important
  keys to writing better software.

  ```
  with open(out_path, 'w') as fh:
      for r in rows:
          fh.write(r)
  ```

Comment: could you elaborate more on the hard-coding path v. command-line parameter statement above? The way I've been debugging is having 3 sample files in a list i.e sample_f = ['file_1.txt', 'file_2.txt']. Then I create a function and use the sample_f list as an input parameter. I don't completely understand you reasoning to use in_path = sys.argv[1] and out_path = sys.argv[2].

Comment: and thank you for taking the time to explain the post above. Its much appreciated.

Comment: @Tim51 I assume you are running your program from the command-line (for example, from a Bash shell, a Windows terminal, or some equivalent): eg, `python your_script.py`. If that's correct, my suggestion is to accept input and output paths as arguments supplied by the user: eg, `python your_script.py small_file.txt`. In other words, parameterize your script, rather than hardcoding the file paths. The general point is this: for testing/debugging purposes, you want to be able to execute your script with smaller inputs and outputs **without editing your source code**.

Comment: I see. I am running my program from the Spyder IDE on Windows 10. But thank you for the tip.