# sort lines in file by negative value in string

Tags: python

I have file with the following lines

```
channel: 6372225 rxLev: -58 name: Right
channel: 6372235 rxLev: -52 name: left 
channel: 4372225 rxLev: -51 name: left 
channel: 1372225 rxLev: -22 name: left 
channel: 6371115 rxLev: -33 name: Right
channel: 6376665 rxLev: -40 name: left 
channel: 6322225 rxLev: -60 name: left 
channel: 6112225 rxLev: -80 name: up
```

how i can sort these lines in same file by the rxLev value using python ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a text file line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120633/how-to-sort-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say the filename is `stackoverflow.txt`:

```
with open('stackoverflow.txt', 'r') as f:
  sorted_list = sorted([item.split(" ") for item in f.readlines()], 
                        key=lambda x: float(x[3]))  # or int

with open('stackoverflow.txt', 'w') as f:
  for sublist in sorted_list:
    f.write(" ".join(word for word in sublist))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply read the contents, sort them and write them back while deleting old contents:

```
with open('your_file.txt', 'r+') as f:
    sorted_contents =  ''.join(sorted(f.readlines(), key = lambda x: int(x.split(' ')[3])))
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.write(sorted_contents)
```

Doing it atomically also make it more error resistant as opposed to opening once for reading and then once again for writing