# How Can I Output The Top Values In Order?

Tags: python, text, text-files

I've got a .txt file  that looks something like this:

```
3 Bob
1 Bill
12 Ollie
7 Joe
5 Ben
etc...
```

And I'm trying to print the top 5 values, with their corresponding names, sorted from highest to lowest. This is the code I have right now:

```
f = open('Scores.txt', 'r')
scores = f.read()
scores_list = scores.split('\n')
f.close()
highscores = sorted(scores_list, reverse=True) 
print(highscores)
```

But this doesn't seem to work properly unless all of the numbers are 1-digit. Since it only looks at the first character of each line (unless their are multiple lines with the same 1st character, then it will look at the 2nd character and so on) it is outputting something like this:

```
['7 Joe', '5 Ben', '3 Bob', '12 Ollie', '1 Bill', '']
```

How can I get it to output it properly sorted?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html - use a key function that returns the first character(s) as a number.

Comment: Does [How to sort a text file line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120633/how-to-sort-a-text-file-line-by-line) answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have split lines so you access part before " " and then typecast `str` into `int` to sort it.

```
f = open('Scores.txt', 'r')
scores = f.readlines()
scores_list = []
f.close()

for each in scores:
    scores_list.append(int(each.strip().split(" ")[0]))

highscores = sorted(scores_list, reverse=True) 
print(highscores)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possiable solution:

```py
with open('Scores.txt', 'r') as f:
    scores_list = f.read().split("\n")
highscores = sorted(scores_list, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[0]), reverse=True)
print(highscores)
```

Comment: I got: 'IndexError: list index out of range' when I tried this

Comment: You probably have empty lines in your ```Scores.txt``` file. Remove them and it should work.