# Sort Lines from File with Numbers

Tags: python-3.x

i need your help again, i don't know how to proceed

I have a file and it looks like this:

```
file.txt:

005-test1
039-test1
008-test1
009-ttest1
003-test1 97F199F
015-test1 C7264DF9
007-test1 5AD753A0
059-test1 CF4BFD2F
```

I would like to have the file sorted by number in ascending order so that it looks like this here

```
003-test1 97F199F
005-test1
007-test1 5AD753A0
008-test1
009-ttest1
015-test1 C7264DF9
039-test1
059-test1 CF4BFD2F
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to do it

Comment: where is the problem? reading the file? splitting the lines? sorting the list of lines? You do not even try to do it ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort a text file line-by-line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56120633/how-to-sort-a-text-file-line-by-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following snippet does what you want:

```
def sort_lines(inputfile, outputfile):
    lines = open(inputfile).readlines()
    with open(outputfile, "w") as out:
        out.write("".join(sorted(lines)))

sort_lines("file.txt", "outputfile.txt")
```

where we used:

- [open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function to open the input and ouput files,
- [readlines](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html) to read in each line from the opened file,
- [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function to sort the lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
dic = {}
with open("file.text", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        number = int(line.split("-")[0])
        dic[number] = line
for x in sorted(dic):
    print(dic.get(x))
```